# jquery build http query string

Tags: jquery, string, url

I have an object like this:

```
Object
    id: "myid"
    token: "sometoken"
```

I need to build a HTTP query-string and get something like this:

```
http://domain.com/file.html?id=myid&token=sometoken
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
​var obj = {
        id    : 'myid',
        token : 'sometoken'
    };

alert($.param(obj));
```

You can use `$.param()` to create your query-string parameters. This will alert `id=myid&token=sometoken`.

> This function is used internally to convert form element values into a
>   serialized string representation.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RdGDD/

And docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param

Answer (score 23):

```
var obj = { id: 'myid', token: 'sometoken' };
var url = 'http://domain.com/file.html?' + $.param(obj);
```