# jquery .load passing data as array in URL and trying to recover this array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to pass data to a server using load method like that:

```
$('.myform').load( "View/editEntregador.php", data, function() { });
```

The url I get is:

```
View/editEntregador.php?Array ( [id] => 67 [nome] => Augusta Ap Raym...)
```

So this data is been passed as an array in the URL. I can´t find a way to extract that array to an array variable in php that I can use in my page.

Any ideia?

UPDATE:

This is how the array is:

```
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
    [id] => 67
    [nome] => Augusta Ap Raymo Longo
    [data_inicio] => 13/03/2016
    [observacao] => 
    [numero] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4567
            [1] => 991655725
            [2] => 22222222
            [3] => 333333333
        )

    [complemento] => 
    [cep] => 14076160
    [estado] => SP
    [cidade] => Ribeirão Preto
    [bairro] => Independência
    [tipo_logradouro] => Rua
    [logradouro] =>  Brigadeiro Tobias de Aguiar
    [ddd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 16
        )

    [id_veiculo_tipo] => 1
    [placa] => bse3012
    [descricao_veiculo] => 
)
```

I am getting undefined index trying $_POST['id'].

Comment: Could you post how your data array is created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery build http query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726315/jquery-build-http-query-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var data = { id: 67, nome: 'Augusta Ap Raymo Longo'};
$('.myform').load( "View/editEntregador.php", data, function() { });
```

If your data is coming from $_POST then you will need to make a foreach loop to generate the data array like the example above.

**Example :**

```
echo 'var data={};'."\n";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
  echo "data.".$key."='".addslashes($value)."';\n";//addslashes to escape possible slashes in your string
}
echo '$(\'.myform\').load( "View/editEntregador.php", data, function() { });';
```